# Potential difference and gravitation

Tags: potential-energy

If I take a ball from the ground and take it to the top of 3m tower ,if I drop it, is it due to the fact that potential energy is converted to kinetic energy and it starts to fall or it falls under the influence of gravity?

Answer (score 2):

It falls due to gravity and as result potential energy gets converted into kinetic energy of the ball.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is more precise as the concept of conservative field or force (here the gravitational) comes before potential energy or potential associated with it.

However, usually one term is used for the explanation of other. As the Work-Energy theorem states work done changes the kinetic energy of the system. Hence, first work is done against the gravity which in turn is stored as potential energy.